# How does the compiler generate a closure from a deleted-default-ctor lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to know how a lambda with a deleted-default constructor can be used this way:

```
[](){}; // how is this translated by the compiler?
```

But this doesn't work:

```
auto l = [](){std::cout << "lambda expr\n";}; // which ctor is invoked?

decltype (l) g; // doesn't work
```

- Because prior to C++ 20 it doesn't work but C++ 20 makes lambda default-constructible.
- If there is no constructor to call, how is it that object comes into existance?

Comment: "`[](){}; // how is this translated by the compiler?`" - put it into https://godbolt.org/ or disassemble the generated binary and you'll know.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Previously there was no invokable default ctor, now there is. Is there a problem? Are you asking how the compiler managed to make things work _before_ said ctor was available to us? Lambdas are magic, man! Doesn't really matter what source code the compiler authors used to make it work, surely?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I am so clear: I said in C++11 standard it said that a lamda that doesn't capture any object then that lambda has a deleted-default ctor thus in such expression how can a closure be constructed while the default-ctor being deleted: `[]{}`?

Comment: @Maestro Because the standard says so..! It's really just as simple as that. The compiler can do things you can't do, because the standard says so (and because otherwise we would have no lambdas).

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to call a default c'tor when creating a lambda object from a lambda expression. It has special logic in place, most likely. Might be frustrating for you to hear, but it works because the C++ standard says it should work, and compiler writers make it happen.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Exactly you get my point! Yea how that magic occur? I'm really confused about it? If someone asks me the same question should I answer that "a magic sugar" or something else that I don't see reasonable?

Comment: It's also not the only instance of things working this way. A `std::initializer_list` is [limited in how user programs can construct it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/initializer_list). And yet, the standard says that `{1, 2, 3}` can simply become a `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit like asking: if `int` has no constructor, then where does the `int` object come from when an integer literal is evaluated?

The compiler can create objects without calling a constructor, simply by generating the assembly or machine code that is required to set up the object in memory. It just doesn't let YOU create objects of various class types without calling a constructor. (Although, in C++20, this will change thanks to [P0593](https://wg21.link/P0593).)

When the compiler sees an expression that contains a lambda-expression, it just goes ahead and generates the code that sets up the closure object in memory. It is not obligated to package that code as a function, the way the code in a constructor would be packaged. It's even possible that the compiler generates some constructor that only it knows how to call. From the user's point of view, there is no constructor involved.

Comment: Heh, jinx, just used the `int` example myself :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler isn't writing C++; it is not subject to the same rules that we are.

Until C++20 *we* couldn't default-construct a closure type using C++. But that doesn't change the fact that the standard says a lambda expression produces an object of closure type. So, the compiler has to make it do that thing, and it never had to go through a default constructor to do it. That's fine! There was never any rule that said it had to use that sort of machinery.

I'm sorry there isn't a more satisfying answer, but it's really just "because the standard says so".

See also: how come the compiler can define a built-in type (e.g. `int`) when we can't? Because!